# Initialize Any Union Member (designated initializer)

Tags: c++, c++20

When declaring a union, e.g.

```
union u
{
  int x;
  float y;
};
```

you can construct the union as follows:

```
u integer { .x = 10 };
u fraction { .y = 10.f };
```

Suppose I have a pointer to member,

```
auto union_member_pointer = &u::y;
```

What syntax allows me to abstractly assign to that member of the union? i.e.

```
u unknown { .*union_member_pointer = { } }; // doesn't work
```

Answer (score 2):

Designated initialization is not permitted to be dynamic. It is applied to the names of members, not of member pointers or anything of the like.

Comment: Then consider `union_member_pointer` as `constexpr`, which it is in my use-case. What can I do now?

Comment: @nowi: Nothing. As stated, you have to use names; a member pointer isn't a name.

Comment: That stinks. Looks like I'll just stick with assigning it normally in the body of the constructor using a member pointer to maintain my abstraction.